# How to insert new data to exact place in Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, axios

Let's say I have the following database on Firebase:

```
"items" : {
    "-LYC_oPtzMyRDZSXPcLY" : {
      "amount" : "HUF 2,500",
      "category" : "home",
      "comment" : "Comment_1",
      "date" : "2019-02-08"
    },
    "-LYC_sXCY-crys5OUj5Y" : {
      "amount" : "HUF 5,000",
      "category" : "restaurant",
      "comment" : "Comment_2",
      "date" : "2019-02-04"
   },
    "-LYC_DXCY-cays5dOdj2R" : {
      "amount" : "HUF 4,000",
      "category" : "food",
      "comment" : "Comment_3",
      "date" : "2019-02-03"
    }
}
```

My "items" are in order according to "date". Now I would like to POST new item after first "item" because that new item will have date 2019-02-06, currently this is what I'm doing:

```
//post new item
axios.post('/items.json', itemData) etc....

//get all items
axios.get('/items.json')
        .then(res => {
            const fetchedItems = [];
            for (let key in res.data) {
                fetchedItems.push({
                    ...res.data[key],
                });
            } etc....

//sort all items like this:
fetchedItems.sort(function (a, b) {
      return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});

//replace "items" with "fetchedItems" on Firebase somehow...
```

Now I have new item inserted and items are sorted according to date. My question is that how can I insert new item at place where I want... faster? I don't want to loop through all the data if I found the place where I would like to put my new "item".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you caring about the order at all when inserting the item? Sorting should only matter when you're retrieving the data, and in that case, simply use the built in functionality: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I thought if I save data in order on Firebase, then reading will be a lot faster. In my case every time if I would like to read data I need to sort it first.